# Prestashop root directory in local

Tags: php, css, themes, prestashop

I have downloaded the prestashop file from the server which is already running and installed in my local
the default theme is selected but  it's not applying any stylesheet 
when i checked through firebug the stylesheet path is wrong for example 
i have `http://localhost/prestashop_live` but the stylesheet path is

```
 http://localhost/global.css
```

How would i append the directory name prestashop_live ? Where i have to change?
 Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for 1.4.x try change it here: config/settings.inc.php

```
define('__PS_BASE_URI__', '/prestashop/');
```

Regards